# resize default magento 1.7 product image

Tags: magento

I have tried everything I could to change the default product size of magento please any help?
I need this to be bigger http://officeresourcegroup.com/new/desks/dmi/dmi-andover-series.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit media.phtml in your theme. There is a resize call that makes the images 265x265.

here is a path for the file in base package, please exchange with your theme directories:

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

look for the line:

$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(265)

Comment: i changed this and it did absolutely nothing? I dont understand why?

Comment: there is an if-else statement there and the resize option is in the else which may not get executed. edit the option in the if block, add resize there. Another useful options for resize are: ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(343, null), this is what I use.

Answer (score 1):

You need change this: $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(265);

I think you are using an external module for the Zoom image, correct? Soon you should change the media.phtml this module. Look in the app/design/frontend/default/default/template/(extension-folder-zoom)/media.phtml  or app/design/frontend/base/default/template/(extension-folder)/media.phtml. Note that (extension-folder) is the module name that you used.

Should you not find anyway, maybe the html is generated in the controller module, but usually not this way.

Another way to figure out which file you should use is the option to debug screens. Watch this video and will not doubt how:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4GLjYHaJig

Comment: Do you think you could shed some insight on changing the following image please thanks! http://officeresourcegroup.com/new/desks/dmi.html